# DMQL-Data Mining Query Language

Tags: data-mining

I'm trying to get some references about DMQL but Google keep viewing the same results no matter what I do.
So any one have some references about DMQL and it's history and syntax ?

Comment: What for? There are a lot of dead ends. Such as the "Java Data Mining" standard, it also is a dead duck in the desert.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a wild guess but there is a [workshop](http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/lml/) in ECML about Languages for Data Mining and Machine Learning. If you follow the committee members, some of them will probably have some references to DMQL... sorry not to be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot
I needed the information for assignment
Again thanks a lot